# Textblock or Label text vertical stack from bottom to top

Tags: wpf

How can I make a WPF `Textblock` control stack it's text from bottom to top, instead of top to bottom when using a fixed height? Here is an example of what I mean:

`Textblock` *with one line*

```
***********                My Text ***
***********   instead of   ***********
My Text ***                ***********
```

`Textblock` *with two lines*

```
***********                My Text is 
My Text is    instead of   bigger ****
bigger ****                ***********
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply setting the `VerticalAlignment` property to `Bottom`? If you have something that surrounds the actual text, you could for example place the `TextBlock` in a `Grid` or `Border` and set the height of this one:

```
<Border Background="Yellow" Height="300">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom">one line at the bottom</TextBlock>
</Border>
```